# How do I optimize this code to be more pythonic?

Tags: python, django

This is a code snippet I wrote, which I consider is not Pythonic basically because of the if condition ladder.

This snippet is of a custom class that is used for backend processing,

```
def _get_item(self, **kwargs):
    """ returns an object if object exists else None"""
    return self.model.objects.get_object_or_none(**kwargs)


def get_object(self, info=None):
    """ gets an object with given info """
    if info:
        self._validate_info(info=info)
        name = self._info.get('name', '')
        slug = self._info.get('slug', '')
        if slug:
            obj = self._get_item(slug=slug)
        elif name:
            obj = self._get_item(name=name)
        else:
            obj = self._get_item(name=name, slug=slug)
        if obj:
            return obj
```

here I need to optimize `get_object()` method. the `._validate_info()` validates the given `info` which basically checks and stores the required values in `self._info` which is a dictionary, later retrieved with `.get()` method.

How do I make this code Pythonic and less mess?

Comment: Better question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). (1) What's the point of allowing `info` to be `None` if the function uses `if info` at the top? (2) In Python, it's `if info is not None:` not `if info:`. (3) `if slug` and `elif name` looks weird; is only one present in `self._info`? (4) Just return `obj`, the `if obj` is currently redundant.

Comment: I'd recomend you to check [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch15s09.html)

Comment: If this were posted on Code Review, likely it would be asked what the code is actually doing, in other words context.

Comment: @ChrisP (1) to fail safe. (2) its okay, I except values like empty strings`''` and empty dicts `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `self._info` only contains `name` and `slug` data, you could write something like:

```
def get_object(self, info=None):
    self._validate_info(info)
    return self._get_item(**self._info)
```

To explain a bit more:

```
if obj:
    return obj
# end of function
```

is equivalent to:

```
if obj:
    return obj
else:
    return None
```

And that is the same as just doing `return obj` with no if test (assuming `obj` is only falsy if it's `None`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in Django that helps you gets a value from a model or return a 404

```
from Django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


get_object_or_404(Model, slug=slug)
```